# How can I register ConEmu to run with DevCpp in Windows?

Tags: windows, dev-c++, conemu

I've installed ConEmu console, I've registered ConEmu as the default console for Windows system, but wxDev-C++ is still triggering the standard cmd.exe.

How can I bind ConEmu to DevCpp?

(The installed version of wxDev-C++ is 7.4.2.569, and the system is an old Windows XP).

**EDIT1:** Now I have attached DevCpp to ConEmu by **Settings/Features/Integration"**, then **"Force ConEmu as default terminal for console" (checkboxed)**, and in **"List of hooked executables"** I added **devcpp.exe**.

The result is that DevCpp triggers ConEmu, but the output of my test program is not shown.

The C program is the following:

```
// c:/cproj/experiment.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   for (long long i= 0; i<20; i++)
      printf("%d ",i);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

In normal cmd.exe, it works well:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

When ConEmu is active, the ConEmu window has title "cmd.exe".
The ConEmu subwindow has title: "<1>.exe" and shows:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Versión 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\cproj>
```

The "real" console shows exactly the same output.

**EDIT2:** DevCpp shows me the following information:

```
Compiler: Default GCC compiler
Executing  gcc.exe...
gcc.exe "C:\cproj\experiment.c" -o "nul"   -std=c99 -pedantic  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\include"  -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\wx\gcc_lib" -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\lib" 
nul.exe: final close failed: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Execution terminated
```

**EDIT3** (I solved: see my answer below).

Comment: Have you specified DevCpp executable in the "Default terminal" settings? Show screenshot.

Comment: I have found the setting option "Setup task.../Features/Integration" and then "List of hooked executables". I've added devcpp.exe. Now devcpp triggers ConEmu, but my C-compiled program is not seen or executed (it is a simple test program that prints the numbers 1 to 10000 with printf).

Comment: Show screenshot of your executable running without integration and in the ConEmu tab. BTW, there is system(!) menu available on any program. ConEmu has it too. Also, menu may be called from tab bar.

Comment: Also, don't understand what do you meaning "not seen it executed". You may reveal "real console" window with CtrlWinAltSpace. What is there?

Comment: @Maximus I've added screenshots in the question. The "real console" shows the same output. The program experiment.exe is not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

In up-right corner of ConEmu there is an icon named **BufferHeight mode...**.
This icon must be pressed in order to select **BufferHeight mode is ON (scrolling is enabled)**.

Under this mode, the program runs as expected, showing the numbers 0 to 19.

Comment: Very, very strange. 1. It must not affect execution or printing, no one reported that. 2. It affect buffer height if current console, but not started new one (your just started experiment). 3. What about your "edit 2"? This error must not relate to ConEmu. I'd like to understand what was happens, bug or not... Btw screenshots are deleted already?

Comment: @Maximus Sorry maximus: I added the text transcription of the screenshots, and not the real screenshots. I have installed ConEmu in another machine with Windows XP and DevCpp, and the buffer turned OFF or ON. Everything worked without problems. I think the first machine probably have strange problems with Windows XP itself. Do you really need the screenshots? They just had what I mention in the details of the question.

Comment: When devcpp attempted to communicate with ConEmu, telling the name of the program "experiment.exe", something failed. The name of the program was bad read (or received) by ConEmu (only the last part of the pathname was obtained!!!). But I cannot reproduce this error anymore (I don't know why). Try by running a console application in wxdev-cpp and check how the string containing the name of the compiled program (like my "experiment.exe") is read by ConEmu. There, it is a potencial source of bugs. That is all what I can tell you about that. Thanks by ConEmu. It's a great project. I'm happy now!

Comment: Ok. If the problem appears once more - please take logs with ProcessMonitor tool. May be something wrong with execution parameters or anything else...